# Handling stomp ACK commands in Spring Websockets message-broker

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, broker

I need to handle ACK commands from client in custom way. What is the best way to integrate logic?
My web-socket config:

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
        <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/ws">
            <websocket:sockjs/>
        </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
        <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

Comment: Can you tell us how you need to handle the ACK command?

Comment: Basic use case: log info of delivery to db.